# How do move an image while page scrolls?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have seen this new look on many modern websites. The user scrolls down, and the image moves its position within its frame.

Here is an example: https://twitter.com/SDFD

Is this easy to implement with CSS?

Thanks.

Comment: are you talking about parallax effects? http://boy-coy.com/

Comment: That link does not appear to demonstrate what you describe.

Comment: Yes, I believe these are parallax effects. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: fixed`. Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) for more info.

Comment: Yes, but would this generate the same effect as is shown with the background image when you scroll a new twitter page?

Comment: What effect are you trying to simulate, the effect of the firetrucks image, or the one of the bar on top of the page, or some other one?

Comment: The firetrucks. Are you able to see, when you scroll down, the trucks move up faster than the scroll?

Comment: In my browser, they have a rather buggy behavior. I scroll, then about half a second later the image moves down a bit. Is that what you see?